# nodejs sails sybase connection error

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, sybase

```
sybase:
{
  adapter: 'sails-sybase',
  url: 'sybase://user:psw@host:4901/PRD'
}
```

> error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load! error:  error: Trying to use an
>   unrecognized adapter, `sails-sybase`, in datastore `sybase`. This may
>   or may not be a real adapter available on NPM, but in any case it
>   looks like `sails-sybase` is not installed in this app (at least it is
>   not in the expected path within the local `node_modules/` directory).
>
> To attempt to install this adapter, run: npm install sails-sybase
>   --save
>
> error: Could not load Sails app. error:  error: Tips: error:  • First,
>   take a look at the error message above. error:  • Make sure you've
>   installed dependencies with `npm install`. error:  • Check that this
>   app was built for a compatible version of Sails. error:  • Have a
>   question or need help?  (http://sailsjs.com/support)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I get an error when I load the npm command.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no such community supported or sails officially supported adapter for sybase. So this code will not work because sails can not find an adapter named **sails-sybase**

You could instead write a custom adapter or you can use some node module which can help you connect and query sybase. Then you can write your own helper and service class around it to do your db related operations.